# How can I switch line numbering off with the lineno package?

Tags: line-numbering

I often use the lineno package in order to number all lines of a draft document, e.g., a paper that I have to send out for peer review. One inconvenient aspect of it, though, is that when I need to produce the final version of a document, i.e., one without line numbers, I need to manually remove all \linelabel’s from the document, since just removing the \linenumbers command won’t do. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Where do you use the `\linelabel` commands? Do you `\ref`erence them somewhere?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example of your use-case that comprehensively describes the setup and what you're trying to avoid (via code)?

Comment: why do you use `\linelabel` ? but you can always put `\newcommand\linelabel[1]{}` in your preamble ifyou comment out the package so it does nothing